# Error: "A connection to the bus can't be made" while trying to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I removed Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.

There may be some important files missing because I format some volumes.

This time I choose Ubuntu 18.04, and I put the installing image on USB flash disk, everything goes well before I click install.

[image: I click install]

I find that I can't install it, and there is an error.

[image: failed to connect the bus]

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this same issue 2 years back and here is the workaround that just worked for me.

I was unable to boot (Ubuntu 20.04) while installing (from Live USB) like you and the screen was stuck with this error message, I waited for about 15 minutes but nothing progressed. So, I just started randomly pressing arrow keys out of frustration, and I don't know how, but booting started progressing.

Then I installed the OS and did reboot. But again, the screen stuck while booting. I forced shutdown with the power button. Searched for the issue and found out that setting **nomodeset** option while booting in the boot time configuration can help me rid of this issue.

### Solution

**Step 1: Setting nomodeset while booting after OS installation**

1. In the boot menu, when the cursor is on "ubuntu's kernal" (generally topmost) press "e" to edit its booting configurations.
2. Find the line starting with "linux".
3. Replace -> “quiet splash” with “nomodeset” or add “nomodeset” before “quiet splash”
4. Press –> CTRL + X to boot

**Step 2: After booting successfully, now permanently set this nomodeset in your grub config file**

1. Open file **/etc/default/grub**
2. Append **nomodeset** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** that will make it as **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"**
3. Save and exit

**Step 3: Update grub and system**

1. sudo update-grub
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt upgrade

Now when I did reboot the system, the error was gone.

### References:

1. How to set **nomodeset**: [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/)
2. A helpful discussion on ubuntu forum: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132
3. My own blogpost on the issue: https://misternarayan.wordpress.com/2020/05/17/fixed-error-a-connection-to-the-bus-cant-be-made-in-linux-booting/